# Size limitations of different sections in process image

Tags: process, executable

I know that the maximum size of the stack by default is 2 MiBi on Windows and 8 MiBi on Linux. What is the size limitation of

1. the text segment
2. the data segment

The reason I need to know this is that I am embedding some data inside the executable file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the text and data segments are allocated statically and the limits on these are configurable in the OS in most cases, and theoretically could be as much as your memory can bear, bearing in mind the 3GB limit on 32-bit linux, and 4GB limit on 32-bit windows platforms (including memory used in devices such as cache and graphics memory).

On linux or unix, the following applies as well, there is an OS-defined limit, in general, and you can also specify more specific limits. By default, the general limit might vary between linux/unix distributions.  Also consult http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit the man page about this for information on how to obtain what your limit is set to. Note that the documentation appears to be out of date: RLIMIT_DATA no longer affects the heap on modern linux because the allocation function used changed.

Windows does not have a configurable limit, but uses a DWORD variable for its static process memory, see also https://superuser.com/questions/667593/is-it-possible-to-run-a-larger-than-4gb-exe. This means that your actual process cannot be larger than 4GB.

So in general:
1,2) On linux: Configurable, depends on distribution. On Windows: 4GB.

Comment: Does a larger executable imply a smaller heap? Isn't Stack+Heap+Text+Data limited by address space, which is 2GB on 32-bit system.